# Note item not found using Lotusscript getting content of a view in IBM Notes client

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a script to that works fine on my R9.0.1 client, something like this

```
Set view2All = dbArchive2.GetView("($Lookup_RGNoAll)")
```

the view name is: ($Lookup_RGNoAll)

the view alias is: lookup_rgnoAll
I have tried both the name and the alias when setting the view

any of these rows will produce the same error

```
alt1: print cstr(view2all.AllEntries.count)
alt2: Set all2dc = view2All.GetAllDocumentsByKey(RGNo, True)
```

when my customer try to run it on his 8.5 client he get the following error:

**ERROR Notes error: Note item not found (($Lookup_RGNoAll))**

worth mentioning here is that the dbArchive2 is a about 60Gb at my customer and the script is running in another database.  but the view can be opened using  the customer id in the client without any problems.

In the code there is also a check if the database is open and view exist, like so:

```
Set dbArchive2 = session.GetDatabase(srv,arc1)
If Not dbArchive2.IsOpen Then Exit Sub

If view2All Is Nothing Then exit sub
```

So there seem to be some strange things going on when accesing methods of the view in lotusscript, probabaly because he is using R8.5 but I am not sure.

I can't test my code in R9 at my customer , only locally at my machine so can't tell if there is a lotusscript bug in 8.5 or if there is something wrong with the database.

Anyone know what could be causing this and how can I workaround it?

thanks

Thomas

Comment: Have you tried running updall -R -T on the view?

Comment: you should add that as an answer

Comment: Okay. I've put it in as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess here is that there's something damaged in the view index.  Try running updall -R -T on the view, and see if that resolves the problem.